# Java 8 method using streams explanation

Tags: java, java-stream

I am kinda new in Java 8 and i am trying to understand what the following code does

```
@Override
public Optional<String> getMostFrequentLastName(final List<User> users) {
    return 
      users.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getLastName, Collectors.counting()))
       .entrySet()
       .stream()
       .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() >= 2)
       .reduce((e1, e2) -> 
           e1.getValue() < e2.getValue() ? e2 :
           e1.getValue() > e2.getValue() ? e1 :
           new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(null, e1.getValue()))
       .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
}
```

Can anyone explain in details what is going on here?

Comment: Which part is confusing you *specifically*? What is not clear after reading documentation of used methods?

Comment: The most confusing  i think for me is the reduce  and map parts

Comment: `map` just means "apply this function to the input" - note that is `Optional.map`, not `Stream.map` (but the effective meaning is the same). That `reduce` is a bit of an eyeful though. Not sure why you'd want to create a new entry with `null` as the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The most confusing i think for me is the reduce and map parts

The `reduce` operation is quite confusing here:

```
        .reduce((e1, e2) -> e1.getValue() < e2.getValue() ? e2 :
                e1.getValue() > e2.getValue() ? e1 :
                        new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(null, e1.getValue()))
```

which I'd say is partly confusing down to the formatting:

```
    .reduce(
        (e1, e2) ->
            e1.getValue() < e2.getValue()
                ? e2
                : e1.getValue() > e2.getValue()
                    ? e1
                    : new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(null, e1.getValue()))
```

(but only partly).

Remember that `e*.getValue()` is the number of occurrences of a name. So, this is saying:

- If name1 occurred fewer times than name2, name2 is the best name we have found so far
- If name2 occurred more times than name1, name1 is the best name we have found so far
- Otherwise, they occurred the same number of times - in this case, make up a new name, `null`, and return that with the number of occurrences.

Returning the name `null` is a bit confusing, without knowing your requirements - what it seems is that this is actually aiming to find the name with the maximal number of occurrences, but only if there are no other names with that number of occurrences.

The `reduce` will return an `Optional<Map.Entry<String, Long>>` (which is present provided there is at least one person in the list). The subsequent `.map(Map.Entry::getKey)` simply extracts the name and discards the count.

Note that in the case of the maximal count occurring for many names, `getKey` returns `null`, meaning the method overall returns `Optional.empty()`.